# Configuring OpenLDAP 2.4 for Outlook address book lookup

Tags: centos7, openldap

Can someone kindly point me to a howto on how to configure OpenLDAP 2.4 so that I may use the directory from Outlook?

So far, the articles I've found (such as https://www.maxcrc.de/en/use-openldap-as-address-book-for-outlook-en/) mention the steps for previous versions, but the filenames in 2.4 have changed. Furthermore, I see that the officePerson.schema file does exist in /etc/openldap/schema directory. I assume that this means that I need to add this schema by first creating an LDIF file and then using ldapmodify?

I have openLDAP installed on a CentOS 7 server. All the entries I have created so far use the organizationalPerson structural class. Would I need to recreate them? If so, can I add the needed attributes to the organizationalPerson class so I wouldn't have to recreate everything? I am using LDAP to login to a large number of Linux machines via ssh, Java apps running under WebLogic, etc.